# Is it illegal if I convert or reimplement java code to kotlin with same declaration and API?

Tags: java, kotlin

For example, the source code of java class `java.io.File` is :

```
public class File
    implements Serializable, Comparable<File>
{
    /* -- Constructors -- */

    /**
     * Internal constructor for already-normalized pathname strings.
     */
    private File(String pathname, int prefixLength) {
        this.path = pathname;
        this.prefixLength = prefixLength;
    }

    /**
     * Internal constructor for already-normalized pathname strings.
     * The parameter order is used to disambiguate this method from the
     * public(File, String) constructor.
     */
    private File(String child, File parent) {
        assert parent.path != null;
        assert (!parent.path.equals(""));
        this.path = fs.resolve(parent.path, child);
        this.prefixLength = parent.prefixLength;
    }

    public boolean createNewFile() throws IOException {
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (security != null) security.checkWrite(path);
        if (isInvalid()) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid file path");
        }
        return fs.createFileExclusively(path);
    }

    public boolean delete() {
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (security != null) {
            security.checkDelete(path);
        }
        if (isInvalid()) {
            return false;
        }
        return fs.delete(this);
    }
}
```

If I convert these code to kotlin, whatever by using IntelliJ IDEA copy&paste translate function, or reimplement it manually, and rewrite some internal implementation.
It maybe look like this:

```
open class File : Serializable, Comparable<File> {
    /* -- Constructors -- */

    /**
     * Internal constructor for already-normalized pathname strings.
     */
    private constructor(pathname: String, prefixLength: Int) {
        this.path = pathname
        this.prefixLength = prefixLength
    }

    /**
     * Internal constructor for already-normalized pathname strings.
     * The parameter order is used to disambiguate this method from the
     * public(File, String) constructor.
     */
    private constructor(child: String, parent: File) {
        assert(parent.path != null)
        assert(!parent.path.equals(""))
        this.path = fs.resolve(parent.path, child)
        this.prefixLength = parent.prefixLength
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    open fun createNewFile(): Boolean {
        //My implementation code here...
    }

    open fun delete(): Boolean {
        //My implementation code here...
    }
}
```

Suppose it will be used in my personal and commercial application, is it violate Oracle's JDK commercial or GPLV2.0 License?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a legal opinion

Comment: I don't see anything in the question related to Oracle Database, so probably that tag should go.

Comment: Oracle tag removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe nobody care this legal opinion, but I think it important for the decision of some technical questions.
So far I've got one answer which I think is right.
https://qr.ae/TWpiQ2